# $27^x+3^{x+1} = 100$. Find an exact solution in terms of logarithms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> $27^x+3^{x+1} = 100$. Find an exact solution in terms of logarithms.

I've tried this in many different ways and can't find any leeway. I also can not find anything to help me online.

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: And  what  are  some  of  those  different  ways $?$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Let $y=3^x$ and get a cubic equation for $y$. Then $x = \log_3 y$.

Comment: The expression for $y $is not pretty, even if you know the formula for cubic equations.

Comment: Possibly $3^{x+2}$ was intended, then it is nice.

Comment: Definitely not: $y=a+a^{-1}$, where $a=\sqrt[3]{50+\sqrt{2501}}$